# Typescript infinitive interface infer itself

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I'm looking for a way to make a type/interface from this API response, The nested `comments` property is challenging for me.

```
"data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "comment": "This is the comment to another comment",
                "approved": true,
                "archived": 0,
                "pinned": 0,
                "reported": 0,
                "created_at": "2022-06-24T06:12:25.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-06-24T06:12:25.000000Z",
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "comment": "This is the comment to another comment",
                        "approved": true,
                        "archived": 0,
                        "pinned": 0,
                        "reported": 0,
                        "created_at": "2022-06-24T06:12:37.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2022-06-24T06:12:37.000000Z",
                        "comments": [
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "comment": "This is the comment to another comment",
                                "approved": true,
                                "archived": 0,
                                "pinned": 0,
                                "reported": 0,
                                "created_at": "2022-06-24T06:32:52.000000Z",
                                "updated_at": "2022-06-24T06:32:52.000000Z",
                                "comments": [],
                                "commented": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "first_name": "Test",
                                    "last_name": "Testi",
                                    "full_name": "Test Testi"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 4,
                                "comment": "This is the comment to another comment",
                                "approved": true,
                                "archived": 0,
                                "pinned": 0,
                                "reported": 0,
                                "created_at": "2022-06-24T06:32:57.000000Z",
                                "updated_at": "2022-06-24T06:32:57.000000Z",
                                "comments": [],
                                "commented": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "first_name": "Test",
                                    "last_name": "Testi",
                                    "full_name": "Test Testi"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "commented": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "first_name": "Test",
                            "last_name": "Testi",
                            "full_name": "Test Testi"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "commented": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "first_name": "Test",
                    "last_name": "Testi",
                    "full_name": "Test Testi"
                }
            },
        ],
```

Comment: Just make `comments` contain a list of `comments`? Like: `interface IComment { comments: Array<IComment>}`?

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface Comment {
  id: number;
  comment: string;
  approved: boolean;
  archived: boolean;
  pinned: boolean;
  reported: boolean;
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
  comments: Comment[];
  commented: {
    id: number;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    full_name: string;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=293#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBhOBbDEB2wCwAUEQJZ4QBOAZgIYDG06WuwAIjcDVAN5FRQkAJgC4oOAK4YARpQDcfKHUzY8ogM7AKZAObzC-GmDAU4ANwgioUhABsINHHoMU6ACxLnLE6XIVgyOBai3jIUTlAUEGBwFMBBYpKh4XSRHBYA+hzqmjrh4mCCaYKZwNlaOLoKSsx4aqJMKmwcNADaALrJyizxAKpqvoQAvkSk5NT00H2UPApCwYkD-FQkFBrpODTYZbkKNjRrG1tQGuWV+lBU4jY265sQ2xV6w8SEZHHjDFDsnDPnhZz1Lp4b6tDpEZ5EJQ4DRQf40UQg5C-fhw0QtBT8Xjnfj8OZQACMABoMTjqo1RAAiAAq7jUAjpwFc0DJLCgwEQDjgjOmLLwFOJ2JxhmMZnimnEEAFOKFLncnlEAAYpdKoP4cIFLEqSfxItFYvEtYL+Cl7HFilkoBSAEwKq1WgC0CoAbParQAWKnO4T4q3CK0AVgAdAqQ6GAFr87VQfL-DIW622h3O10er0+v1B0PhyNGxRA4B1KDo3OYqPSvFW5Uq0n5yk0kh0htspl5mrANkcnBcpkUVuNHPV6XCkzytkUCVVwc0WUeA2T6tqjWK+cq3UxM3Lsuk1JmkqUm12x0u92ep3e30AZgA7MGswqIyvpTGinvLQek8fU2f09fb1mH1uxr5oWxaDiqWJgdWeIXo+g68qUlr1o2DItvBHZQJy3K9vBA6QUORgjmK46SoBKrTm4s6arBC4BHOpHSmu+pUfR26mnGCEJoeyYnl6F6+v6Vp-tm1Eqs+u7xu+R4pqewh8cIAlCSGAElnBwFom0InSvB8QQXhKp4kSLHSssqzALcRzUhAGi4XpOJ7Acdx1lZwAkDZtkXFcNyHPciHOVAVLOa5mk4oMwWhSxum2XibrBUBbZ1rS9LNsy+boZhPZ9iwbl4cOoqWOKJEqdW5FynRRUqouZXuREUTrlV7kmi+EmJlJPFnnJ-o3ne97ZZBYnsfuLXcV+sn8V1d7KdV8EgRpRmZeQliRe5BmxTiJkORZAXWat-D2WZ3lORoQVzUsnnmT5lkwltLm9WB4Xlfw914bN5XaYtLErSx637Y5vnbSxe3nYdN3BZc1xA397bXcd5VPYOcPSi91ZvaIS3lpYhkqd9EOXcAt1QIDB2QzDYFg15v24-5gW9QjUBwy9gx6JCcDQnAdiBjYcDaAAFHCACUehAA)

`Comment` is part of `lib.dom.d.ts`, so better use `CommentData` instead

```js
interface CommentData {
  id: number;
  comment: string;
  approved: boolean;
  archived: number;
  pinned: number;
  reported: number;
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
  comments: CommentData[];
  commented: User;
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  full_name: string;
}

interface Data {
  data: CommentData[];
}

const data: Data = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      comment: "This is the comment to another comment",
      approved: true,
      archived: 0,
      pinned: 0,
      reported: 0,
      created_at: "2022-06-24T06:12:25.000000Z",
      updated_at: "2022-06-24T06:12:25.000000Z",
      comments: [
        {
          id: 2,
          comment: "This is the comment to another comment",
          approved: true,
          archived: 0,
          pinned: 0,
          reported: 0,
          created_at: "2022-06-24T06:12:37.000000Z",
          updated_at: "2022-06-24T06:12:37.000000Z",
          comments: [
            {
              id: 3,
              comment: "This is the comment to another comment",
              approved: true,
              archived: 0,
              pinned: 0,
              reported: 0,
              created_at: "2022-06-24T06:32:52.000000Z",
              updated_at: "2022-06-24T06:32:52.000000Z",
              comments: [],
              commented: {
                id: 1,
                first_name: "Test",
                last_name: "Testi",
                full_name: "Test Testi",
              },
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              comment: "This is the comment to another comment",
              approved: true,
              archived: 0,
              pinned: 0,
              reported: 0,
              created_at: "2022-06-24T06:32:57.000000Z",
              updated_at: "2022-06-24T06:32:57.000000Z",
              comments: [],
              commented: {
                id: 1,
                first_name: "Test",
                last_name: "Testi",
                full_name: "Test Testi",
              },
            },
          ],
          commented: {
            id: 1,
            first_name: "Test",
            last_name: "Testi",
            full_name: "Test Testi",
          },
        },
      ],
      commented: {
        id: 1,
        first_name: "Test",
        last_name: "Testi",
        full_name: "Test Testi",
      },
    },
  ],
};

console.log(data);
```